# Laravel Eloquent - where relationship field does not equal

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I thought this would be fairly simple but it's not playing ball currently.

I have 2 tables for this question, 'applications' & 'application_call_logs'.

This query needs to return all from the applications table where the latest call log doesn't have a status of X.

Here's the current query:

```
$query = Application::query();

$query->where(function($query) {
    $query->whereDoesntHave('call_logs');
    $query->orWhereHas('latest_call_log', function($q) {
        $q->where('status', '!=', 'not interested');
    });
});

return $query->get();
```

This should return all rows that either have no call logs, or where the latest call log doesn't have the status field equaling a specific string.

This here:

```
$q->where('status', '!=', 'not interested');
```

Seems to have no affect if the call_logs has more than 1 row, even though I'm querying the latest relationship. I've also verified the latest is returning the correct latest record.

The two relationships in the Application model are:

```
public function call_logs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ApplicationCallLog', 'lead_id', 'id');
}

public function latest_call_log()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\ApplicationCallLog', 'lead_id', 'id')->latest();
}
```

Checked the SQL generated:

```
select * from `applications` where (not exists (select * from `lead_call_logs` where `applications`.`id` = `lead_call_logs`.`lead_id`) or exists (select * from `lead_call_logs` where `applications`.`id` = `lead_call_logs`.`lead_id` and `status` != ?))
```

Comment: Perhaps a good idea to check the generated SQL?

Comment: @onlineThomas good shout, just updated the question whilst I take a look too.

Answer (score 0):

there is a solution around should be good for this situation:

i think that this line has the week point of the code:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\ApplicationCallLog', 'lead_id', 'id')->latest();
```

this should be hasMany, but you use hasOne to limit the result to one.

and if you tried:

```
 return $this->hasMany('App\ApplicationCallLog', 'lead_id', 'id')->latest()->limit(1);
```

it simply won't work, because the result will be limited to  ApplicationCallLog for all of the results ....

will, there is a package staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit that is made especially for this situations:

```
composer require staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit:"^1.0"

class Application extends Model
{
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
public function latest_call_log()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ApplicationCallLog', 'lead_id', 'id')->latest()
->limit(1);
}

}

class ApplicationCallLog extends Model
{
use \Staudenmeir\EloquentEagerLimit\HasEagerLimit;
}
```

using this package will limit ApplicationCallLog for every result in your query not one for all of the result, and that will have the same effect for hasOne ....

with this minor enhancement, i think:

```
$q->where('status', '!=', 'not interested');
```

will work ...

more about eloquent-eager-limit package in:

https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit