# Getting just the minimum value on a joined table with Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm

I have 2 tables, `subscriptions` and `subscription_options` like so.

```
subscriptions
------------------------
id    |subscription_name
------------------------
1     |silver
2     |gold


----------------------------------------------------
subscription_options
----------------------------------------------------
id    |subscription_id   |price   |duration (months)
1     |1                 |10      |3
2     |1                 |20      |6
3     |2                 |40      |3
4     |2                 |50      |6
```

`subscriptions` have a one to many relationship with `subscription_options`

```
// Subscription model
public function options() {

    return $this->hasMany('App\SubscriptionOption', 'subscription_id');
}
```

I would like to get the cheapest price for both of my subscription, so i should get 2 rows with `subscription_options`.`id` of `1` and `3` along with all of their columns. How would i do it with laravel eloquent?

These are the things that i have tried, they either gave me an error or return something close to what i am looking for

```
Subscription::with('options')->min('price')->get();


Subscription::with(['options' => function($query) {
         $query->min('price');
     }])->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways to do it, it's a matter of the programmer preferences ...

one of them is to make a sub query that get only the cheapest price and then join that sub query using  [subQuery join](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins)

```
$subQuerysubscription_options=Subscription_option::
selectRaw("id as cheapest_option_id,min(price) as cheapest_price")->groupBy('id');




      $subscription = Subscription::
join('subscription_options','subscription_options.subscription_id','subscriptions.id')->
            joinSub($subQuerysubscription_options, 'subQuerysubscription_options', function ($join) {
                $join->on('subscription_options.id', '=', 'subQuerysubscription_options.cheapest_option_id');
            })
            ->
            select('subscriptions.*','subscription_options.*')

        ->get();
```

since we are using 'join' not 'leftJoin' the query will guarantee that only the rows  that  match those in subQuery will be resulted

option 2:

```
$minCheapestIds=Subscription_option::
selectRaw("id as cheapest_option_id,min(price) as cheapest_price")->groupBy('id')->pluck('cheapest_option_id');
```

now we have a list of cheapest subscription_options ids ...

```
  $values=  Subscription::with(['options' => function($query) use($minCheapestIds){
             $query->whereIn('subscription_options.id',$minCheapestIds);
         }])->get();
```

this means load Subscription 's options where there are in the cheapest ..

Comment: wow, is there something more simple or maybe a bit more elegant? This seems like it would take a lot of resources to do.

Comment: here is option 2

Answer (score 0):

In general, Query builder is faster than ORM (in this case, Eloquent). So you may use query builder to get the expected data as follows:

```
$cheapestSubscriptions = DB::table('subscription_options')
    ->select('subscription_id', DB::raw('MIN(price) as cheapest_price'))
    ->groupBy('subscription_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Why is query builder faster than ORM? Are there any benchmarks?

Comment: Well, ORM provides fluent interfaces to make SQL query but the interface the ORM provides, takes time to get it converted to SQL. Just search for "Why is query builder faster than ORM?" you will get answer that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @OMR and @unclexo for their answer. Your answer helped me get the answer that i was looking for. Here is solution that i ended up using.

**controller**

```
$subscription_plans = Subscription::with(['orderedOptions' => function($query) {
    $query->min('price');
}])->get();
```

**model (Subscription)**

```
public function orderedOptions() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\SubscriptionOption', 'subscription_id')->orderBy('price', 'asc');
}
```

Basically, i sort the the query result in model to be ascending. Then i user the `min()` function in my controller to get the record with the cheapest price. Where there were nothing wrong with the answer that was given, i was looking for a more shorter and strictly eloquent solution.

After doing research, ORM is slower than your normal query builder. But if you are doing simple query and normal CRUD operation, there are basically no difference between ORM and query builder. Now, if your queries are complex and need to handle hundreds to thousands of data, query builder is the way to go.

Comment: you code get only (min('price')) while your question required full column list,
i quote "subscription_options.id of 1 and 3 along with all of their columns.', any way,  you are welcome ...

Comment: @OMR right, the min('price') filters the result from groupBy in my model. In the end, it still holds all of the columns.

Comment: using hasOne for one to many relation is not recommended , one to many relation should take on both sides( hasMnay or belongsTo) this kind of using has side effect, anyway, in your method, there is no need for  $query->min('price'); , remove it and the result will be the same!

Comment: @OMR oh, i didn't know it would have a side effect. Can you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: take a look on this (using hasOne instead of hasMany):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62196091/laravel-eloquent-where-relationship-field-does-not-equal